# Debian Bookworm Preseeding MD5 Checksum error

Tags: debian, preseed, checksum

I have tried everything I can think of and different ways of calculating the MD5 but everytime the install comes back with Checksum does not match. Can anyone help me?

This is my txt.cfg. The checksum I've got for the preseed.cfg below it is c5894cd5c7279e7dbb930fcf99a35e1f.

```
    menu label ^Install
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz preseed/file=install/preseed.cfg preseed/file/checksum=c5894cd5c7279e7dbb930fcf99a35e1f auto=true
```

```
#### Contents of the preconfiguration file (for bookworm)
### Localization
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string AU
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_AU.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select au

### Network configuration

# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# If you have a slow dhcp server and the installer times out waiting for
# it, this might be useful.
-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60

# If you want the preconfiguration file to work on systems both with and
# without a dhcp server, uncomment these lines and the static network
# configuration below.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually

# Static network configuration.
#
# IPv4 example
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.3.123
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.3.1
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.3.1
#d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string Smart-System
d-i netcfg/get_domain string local

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

### Mirror settings
# Mirror protocol:
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
# Default value for the mirror protocol: http.
#d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string ftp.au.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

### Account setup
# Root password, either in clear text
# or encrypted using a crypt(3)  hash.
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $6$zh12OVxOIfmczSmk$Tr7Fqvlyc0EF6aHnPN2rP3bMAEufP0EJUhD48p0LEdQ3x1T70zrCUVAFi8fuuoBUxEGehJENbgsV1KLy6N0np1

# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Developer
d-i passwd/username string dev
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $6$fVL1ZMXbpbNA9NkL$Iv0BHsnsbG.IsLPsNKYIkGv5bSmf22qNyH5PqMN91kJlzc1sAIxmy553Fh5fAKHF2Ani.iosQGMtziLDpvI9A/

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string Australia/Perth

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning
## Partitioning example
# For example, to use the first SCSI/SATA hard disk:
#d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
# In addition, you'll need to specify the method to use.
# The presently available methods are:
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string regular

# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# Force UEFI booting ('BIOS compatibility' will be lost). Default: false.
#d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true
# Ensure the partition table is GPT - this is required for EFI
#d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label select gpt
#d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt

# When disk encryption is enabled, skip wiping the partitions beforehand.
#d-i partman-auto-crypto/erase_disks boolean false

## Partitioning using RAID
# For additional information see the file partman-auto-raid-recipe.txt
# included in the 'debian-installer' package or available from D-I source
# repository.

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation.
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

### Package selection
#tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, web-server, kde-desktop
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard


# Individual additional packages to install
#d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential
# Whether to upgrade packages after debootstrap.
# Allowed values: none, safe-upgrade, full-upgrade
#d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
d-i pkgsel/include openssh-server string libconfig++-dev libjsoncpp-dev mongodb

### Boot loader installation
# Grub is the boot loader (for x86).

# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the UEFI
# partition/boot record if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the UEFI partition/boot record, if
# it also finds some other OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to
# boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false

# Due notably to potential USB sticks, the location of the primary drive can
# not be determined safely in general, so this needs to be specified:
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda
# To install to the primary device (assuming it is not a USB stick):
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string default

### Finishing up the installation
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

### Preseeding other packages
# Depending on what software you choose to install, or if things go wrong
# during the installation process, it's possible that other questions may
# be asked. You can preseed those too, of course. To get a list of every
# possible question that could be asked during an install, do an
# installation, and then run these commands:
#   debconf-get-selections --installer > file
#   debconf-get-selections >> file


#### Advanced options
### Running custom commands during the installation
# d-i preseeding is inherently not secure. Nothing in the installer checks
# for attempts at buffer overflows or other exploits of the values of a
# preconfiguration file like this one. Only use preconfiguration files from
# trusted locations! To drive that home, and because it's generally useful,
# here's a way to run any shell command you'd like inside the installer,
# automatically.

# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
# This command is run immediately before the partitioner starts. It may be
# useful to apply dynamic partitioner preseeding that depends on the state
# of the disks (which may not be visible when preseed/early_command runs).
#d-i partman/early_command \
#       string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
# This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
# still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
# directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
# packages and run commands in the target system.
#d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install zsh; in-target chsh -s /bin/zsh

#Enable ssh for root account
d-i preseed/late_command string echo 'PermitRootLogin yes' >> /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config; echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config; in-target systemctl restart sshd

#Execute script for ignition install
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target chmod +x /ignition/ignition-install-script.sh; in-target /ignition/ignition-install-script.sh;
```